# Why is the Chrome Web store "where to publish" option missing?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When deploying an app or extension from my personal Google Apps based account I see the "where to publish" option in the Chrome Web Store that lets me limit users to my domain.

However when using my employer's account (a Google Apps for business account) that option isn't available at all.

Why is that?  Is there an option in the domain config that needs to be switched somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue awhile back. There is no way to delegate the "where to publish" control to your Google account. If you're an administrator of the Google Apps account, you do get access to the "Where to Publish" feature to share the app privately across your domain. I suspect you may also be able to manually add "tester accounts" with a group email address (e.g. qa_team@example.com) but I haven't tried.

The strange thing is that this is supposedly] not a problem at all for Chrome OS Apps on the Chrome Web Store (but not regular Chrome Apps on the CWS). They even get a little "For domain.name" category that gets added to the Chrome Web Store for Chrome OS people only. Us regular Chrome people get no such love. See: http://support.google.com/chromeos/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2649489